# How do I write this code in list comprehension form and get the value instead of the generator object location?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

So I started learning Python 3 and I came across this problem to display a unique number in a list of numbers. (As in, a number which appears only once)

So to solve that I used this function:

```
def find_uniq(arr):
    for x in arr:
        if arr.count(x) == 1:
            return x
```

The code turns out  to be inefficient for larger data(lists) and gave me a timeout error.

So to counter that I used comprehension but the code is outputting generator object location instead of a value.

```
def find_uniq(arr):
return (x for x in arr if arr.count(x) == 1)
```

Now, I have two questions,
firstly, how do I turn the second code piece to yield me a value and not this (<generator object find_uniq at 0x000001F4F3B64C80>), and
secondly, how do I make the code more efficient.

Thank You!

Comment: What you've written isn't a list-comprehension, it's a generator expression. Either way, why would you expect this to perform any better than your previous solution? It does the same thing.

Comment: The inefficiency is because your code is looping through  the list and for each item it is doing a count, which (under the hood) loops through the list again. That is a time complexity of O(n**2). Look at `collections.Counter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If importing built in modules is allowed. I'd prefer use `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter


def find_uniq(arr):
    counter = Counter(arr)
    return next(k for k, v in counter.items() if v == 1)
```

Complexity is about O(n).

The problem of `arr.count(x)` is that it doesn't remember each count in one interation, and the whole complexity seems to near O(n*n).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Still trying to figure out the time complexity stuff. Quite new to programming in general so I appreciate the guidance.

Comment: updated the answer, should use `counter.items()`

Answer (score 1):

Use square brackets to return it as a list.

```
[x for x in arr if arr.count(x) == 1]
```

Comment: Yes, Thank you that works. Although I need the int value and not a list.

Answer (score 1):

Using parentheses will create a `generator`

> `(x for x in arr if arr.count(x) == 1)`

Use Square brackets for List Comprehension.

> `[x for x in arr if arr.count(x) == 1]`

Comment: Yes, Thank you that works. Although I need the int value and not a list.

Comment: Then simply grab the first element in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this

```
def find_uniq(arr):
    return [x for x in arr if arr.count(x) == 1]
```

this will not return a generator object. For example:

```
output = find_uniq([1,2,3,4,1])
print(*output)
>>>> 2,3,4
```

Comment: Yes, Thank you that works. Although I need the int value and not a list.

Comment: if you want to print it then just `a = find_uniq([1,2,3,4,1]);
print(*a)`

Answer (score 0):

```
[x for x in arr if arr.count(x)==1]
```

This is a list comprehension. It is basically a for loop, just a one liner